# Drawing the circuit from a differential equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance, electrical-resistance, inductance

Can you please help me in modelling a circuit using the differential equation? In the following equation, $u(t)$ is the input voltage and $y(t)$ is the output voltage.

$$y(t)=2u(t)+3\frac{du(t)}{dt}+4\int_0^tu(t)dt.$$

How do I draw a circuit such that the input voltage $u(t)$ and the output voltage $y(t)$ are related by this differential equation?

Comment: Do you mean $y(t)=2u(t)+3\frac{du(t)}{dt}+4\int_0^tu(t)dt$?

Comment: If you do, then I can edit your answer to say that.  But what exactly are you trying to do here anyway?

Comment: Are you looking to solve for $u$?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. So, in this case, we are given with a differential equation as shown above. We need to draw a circuit in which the output voltage is given by y(t) and input voltage is u(t). We need to add components in the circuit such that the output voltage is given by that differential equation.

Comment: This would belong on physics or electrical engineering in that case.

Comment: Yeah this is a circuit theory question, but I feel fairly confident that someone will catch it. A couple of refinements: It is not generally standard to write an integral with limits in terms of the same variable as the independent variable in your integrand(I guess we can live with it though). Double check your equation. Also, this integro differential equation would be a forced rlc circuit if that integral was a second derivative (wishful thinking). as it stands, I do see a forced rc circuit with this integral in the way. More thinking...

Comment: Why don't you try and ask here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

I believe you simply need 4 op-amps. Here is what you need for differentiation and integration.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Integration_and_differentiation

so you simply amplify u by factor 2 with an opamp-circuit then use 2 op-amps for differentiation and integration at the end you should add them all with an opamp another. Here is what you need for ampflication and addition

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Amplifiers

Comment: Do you know any good book which teach to think this way?

Comment: @71GA, see "Analog Computer Techniques":  http://books.google.com/books/?id=lc0mAAAAMAAJ

Comment: You only need three op amps: two integrators and one summing amp.  Multiplication by constants is done with potentiometers (voltage dividers).  Let v(t) = integral(u(t)).  Then u(t) = dv/dt, du/dt = d2v/dt2.  There are your integrators.  To add them all up, you choose appropriate gains for a summer.